# Force Close when pressing back button

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

when I go onto this page and click the back button I get a force close, because it force closes my barcode scanning result doesn't show. how do I stop the app force closing?

```
private EditText mTitleText;
private EditText mBodyText;
private EditText mquantityint;
private EditText mbarcodeint;
private Long mRowId;
private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    setContentView(R.layout.note_edit);

    mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);
    mquantityint = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.quantity);
    mbarcodeint = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.barcode);

    Button barcode2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sbarcode);
    barcode2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
            intent.putExtra("SAVE_HISTORY", false);//this stops saving ur barcode in barcode scanner app's history
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });

    Button confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);

    mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null :
        (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
    if (mRowId == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)
                                : null;
    }

    populateFields();

    confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

private void populateFields() {
    if (mRowId != null) {
        Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(mRowId);
        startManagingCursor(note);
        mTitleText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
        mBodyText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
        mquantityint.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_QUANTITY)));
        mbarcodeint.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BARCODE)));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    saveState();
    outState.putSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveState();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    populateFields();
}

private void saveState() {
    String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
    String body = mBodyText.getText().toString();
    int quantity =Integer.parseInt( mquantityint.getText().toString());
    int barcode =Integer.parseInt( mbarcodeint.getText().toString());
    if (mRowId == null) {
        long id = mDbHelper.createNote(title, body, quantity, barcode);
        if (id > 0) {
            mRowId = id;
        }
    } else {
        mDbHelper.updateNote(mRowId, title, body, quantity, barcode);
    }
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    String contents =null;
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            // String format = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            //Variable set for QR scan result
            EditText sbarcodeno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.barcodeno);
            //Variable set to display custom string above result  
            EditText Result =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.sbarcode);
            //Displays actual  
            sbarcodeno.setText(contents);
            //Edit string here    
            Result.setText(""); 
            // TO DO - Modify code so the result launches in another activity.
        } 
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   this.finish();
   return;
}
}
```

logcat -

```
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {bhavik.smart.shopping/bhavik.smart.shopping.NoteEdit}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2706)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2662)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2640)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at bhavik.smart.shopping.NoteEdit.saveState(NoteEdit.java:138)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at bhavik.smart.shopping.NoteEdit.onPause(NoteEdit.java:126)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:4563)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1195)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
04-13 01:24:47.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2575):     ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a force close because of the lines

```
int quantity =Integer.parseInt( mquantityint.getText().toString());
int barcode =Integer.parseInt( mbarcodeint.getText().toString());
```

in saveState(). One of the TextViews are empty when you are pressing the back button.

Notice this line in the error log

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
```

This is thrown when you run parseInt on an invalid string. In this case, it is telling you the string is empty. You need to check that the string is not empty before running parseInt or throw a try catch around the methods.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
Result.setText("");
```

from your code the you are parsing to string so getting numberformat exception.
just check simple condtions before converting it to integer like below::

```
if(Result.getText()!="" ||Result.getText()!=null)
 int barcode =Integer.parseInt( mbarcodeint.getText().toString());
else
 int barcode =0;
```

in the above you can remove else part as [er you requirement